# Send firebase push notification to group of user

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing geofence app.I want to send push notification of group users on triggering geofence means in IntentService.How can I send push notification using FCM in android??please tell me.

Update:
Problem Solved

Comment: At least show your effort what you tried, Google the same question and then if there is any error while implementing, post the question with your efforts. People here will be happy to help in that case.

Comment: see this FCM doc for group messaging [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this firebase service

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.itw.firebasepushnotificationdemo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.toString());
}
```

you need this too

```
public class NotificationUtils {

    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;


        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);

        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                } else {
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                }
            }
        } else {
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

in manifest declare this

```
<service
    android:name=".Services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

finaly this in splash screen

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("notify")
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

now all the users with specific topic will receive notification hope it will helo :)

Comment: Thanks for reply..My problem is solved.I did it using Retrofit